# mysql takes 50+ times longer to return 20% more records, why?

Tags: python, mysql, cgi

I am using a program that I downloaded and don't have all the details.  This is a web app (Python CGI) that takes user input and queries the mysql database.  What I do know is that when I limit the recordset to 100 results (in the app setting), the results are returned within 2 seconds.  But if I increase the limit just slightly to 120, then it will take over 1.5 minutes to process!  I've tried with several different queries and they all succumb to this problem. This is mind boggling.  Without knowing exactly how the querying is implemented, are there some general mysql settings that I should look into that might mitigate this problem?

**UPDATE**

After more testing, I found that 107 is the magic number that causes this performance problem.  Anything below 107 records returns instantly, whereas anything >= 107 takes at least 1.5 minutes or timing out as it gets bigger.

Comment: Show us the queries along with their explain plans.

Comment: Before I dig through all the modules to find the queries (which might take days), I just wanted to put this question out there in case there are some general mysql settings that might help

Comment: What happens at 50 and 150 results? Is the time spent on the DB? What happens if you query directly on the DB? I can just assume some odd bad logic within the cgi script here that gets you into some sort of exponential hell.

Comment: @alvi Good question.  After more testing, I found that 107 is the magic number that causes this performance problem.  Anything below 107 returns instantly, whereas anything >= 107 takes at least 1.5 minutes or timing out as it gets bigger.

Answer (score 3):

More than likely the query contains some sort of logic which results in an exponential execution time.

For example, if I had a list of locations and want to calculate the distances between them:

For 2 rows, using no optimisation:

```
1 => 2
2 => 1
```

For 4 rows, using no optimisation

```
1 => 2
1 => 3
1 => 4
2 => 1
2 => 3
2 => 4
3 => 1
3 => 2
3 => 4
4 => 1
4 => 2
4 => 3
```

It is clear here that doubling the dataset doesn't simply double the execution time.

Scale this up to your problem and it might explain your performance hit. Without seeing the queries we won't be able to help you much further.